# Raw image to tiff image

Tags: c, image-processing, tiff

Can anyone suggest me a way to convert a 32 bit float type raw image into a 16 bit short type TIFF image in C ?

Any specific library used for this ?

Comment: Just saying that the raw image format is 32 bit float format isn't enough. There are really hundreds, if not thousands, of raw image formats. Can you say *where* the image(s) comes from?

Comment: Actually in my code i am saving the images as .raw files using float type double pointers

Comment: and now i need o convert them to tiff short 16 bit format

Comment: So it's your own format? Then how would anyone else be able to know anything about it, or to use it? Only you yourself can convert it to other formats. My tip: Convert it to a more common format (like 32-bit RGBA) and then there are many tools and libraries that can be used to convert to any other format you want.

Comment: ImageMagick can do that easily. You will need to know the endianness and the size.

Comment: If it's your own code, why not just write the values as 16 bit short values if that is what you want? It's then trivial to add the necessary TIFF container/metadata around the raw values to get the TIFF you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check out raw2tiff(1) here http://linux.die.net/man/1/raw2tiff. This seems to be what your looking for.